# Voting System: Should I use a SQL Trigger or more Code?

Tags: sql-server, language-agnostic, triggers

I'm building a voting system whereby each vote is captured in a votes table with the `UserID` and the `DateTime` of the vote along with an `int` of either **1** or **-1**.

I'm also keeping a running total of `TotalVotes` in the table that contains the item that the user actually voted on.  This way I'm not constantly running a query to `SUM` the Vote table.

My Question is kind of a pros/cons question when it comes to updating the TotalVotes field. With regards to code manageability, putting an additional update method in the application makes it easy to troubleshoot and find any potential problems. But if this application grows significantly in it's user base, this could potentially cause a lot of additional SQL calls from the app to the DB.  Using a trigger keeps it "all in the sql family" so to speak, and should add a little performance boost, as well as keep a mundane activity out of the code base.

I understand that premature optimization could be called in this specific question, but since I haven't built it yet, I might as well try and figure out the better approach right out of the gate.

Personally I'm leaning towards a trigger.  Please give me your thoughts/reasoning.

Comment: Have you determined that `SUM the Vote table` is indeed outside your perf budget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the trigger method for years and was always happier for it.  So, as they say, "come on in, the water's fine."  However, I usually do it when there are many many tables involved, not just one.

The pros/cons are well known.  Materializing the value is a "pay me now" decision, you pay a little more on the insert to get faster reads.  This is the way to go if and only if you want a read in 5 milliseconds instead of 500 milliseconds.

PRO: The TotalVotes will always be instantly available with one read.

PRO: You don't have to worry about code path, the code that makes the insert is much simpler.  Multiplied over many tables on larger apps this is a big deal for maintainability.

CON: For each INSERT you also pay with an additional UPDATE.  It takes a lot more inserts/second than most people think before you ever notice this.

CON: For many tables, manually coding triggers can get tricky.  I recommend a code generator, but as I wrote the only one I know about, that would get me into self-promotion territory.  If you have only one table, just code it manually.

CON: To ensure complete correctness, it should not be possible to issue an UPDATE from a console or code to modify TotalVotes.  This means it is more complicated.  The trigger should execute as a special superuser that is not normally used.  A second trigger on the parent table fires on UPDATE and prevents changes to TotalVotes unless the user making the update is that special super-user.

Hope this gives you enough to decide.

Comment: I like everything about this except for the "code can't update TotalVotes". Just because its a lot of extra work ;-)

Comment: With response to "It takes a lot more inserts/second than most people think before you ever notice this." - I'm thinking that this particular project will never reach the votes/second threshold that make SQL Server puke, as I'm thinking that ratio is in the thousands or more.

Comment: Oh, and FYI - Since I'm using an ORM (Linq to SQL) for all of my data access, I can easily set (in code) `VoteCount` to be `ReadOnly` - takes the pain out of it.

Comment: @Rock, the Linq to SQL thing sounds like it will do just what you need.  You can skip the restriction on preventing updates, I myself only realized that requirement after doing this for some years, and it never was a problem.  But, just understand that it is technically a weakness that has to be guarded against.

Comment: cool, thanks. I've gone with the trigger for now, and I'll monitor it's performance.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to create view on the votes table aggregating the votes as TotalVotes.
Then index the view.

The magic of SQL Server optimizer (enterprise edition only i think) is that when it sees queries of sum(voteColumn)  it will pick that value up from the index on the view of the same data, which is amazing when you consider you're not referencing the view directly in your query!

If you don't have the enterprise edition you could query for the total votes on the view rather than the table, and then take advantage of the index.

Indexes are essentially denormalization of your data that the optimizer is aware of.  You create or drop them as required, and let the optimizer figure it out (no code changes required)  Once you start down the path of your own hand crafted denormalization you'll have that baked into your code for years to come.

Check out [Improving performance with indexed views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx)

There are some specific criteria that must be met to get indexed views working.  Here's a sample based on a guess of your data model:

```
create database indexdemo
go
create table votes(id int identity primary key, ItemToVoteOn int, vote int not null)
go

CREATE VIEW dbo.VoteCount WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
select ItemToVoteOn, SUM(vote) as TotalVotes, COUNT_BIG(*) as CountOfVotes from dbo.votes group by ItemToVoteOn
go
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX VoteCount_IndexedView ON dbo.VoteCount(itemtovoteon)
go
insert into votes values(1,1)
insert into votes values(1,1)
insert into votes values(2,1)
insert into votes values(2,1)
insert into votes values(2,1)
go

select ItemToVoteOn, SUM(vote) as TotalVotes from dbo.votes group by ItemToVoteOn
```

And this query (which doesn't reference the view or by extension it's index) results in this execution plan.  Notice the index is used.  Of course drop the index, (and gain insert performance)

[image]

And one last word.  Until you're up and running there is really know way that you'll know if any sort of denormalization will in fact help overall throughput.  By using indexes you can create them, measure if it helps or hurts, and then keep or drop them as required.  It's the only kind of denormalization for performance that is safe to do.

Comment: Thank you for the detail on this. My question though, doesn't it make sense to have a VoteCount in the table that I'm already selecting, and simply update it when a vote happens? When I'm pulling down way more data than I'm putting up, it doesn't make sense (at least to me) to add additional calculations rather than have the final number already set. Just thinkin'...

Comment: With this kind of indexing, the server should gain the ability to handle the results fairly quickly due to caching and the relative small size of an index. You're not necessarily going to gain a lot of performance by having a column and doing a ton of updates on it then you will out of a fast index.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring --- the indexed view does the same thing as your TotalVotes column.  Every insert into the votes table requires an update of the view (which it can do because the aggregates are additive)  If you find that the cost of summing that column is less than the cost of keeping a running total (which is my bet) then just drop the index.  It all depends on the production environment (which of course changes over time something we hope our code doesn't)  Hope that helps.

Comment: Additional question. I've setup the index as you've stated, but I'm not sure how to access it via LINQ to SQL without making separate db call. Currently I do this `event.EventVotes.Sum(Function(s) s.Vote)` but with the new index, I'm trying to do this `event.EventVoteCount.VoteCount()` but unfortunately it's not available, even though I've made the association between `Events.ID` and `EventVoteCount.EventID` (where EventVoteCount is the Indexed View)

Comment: I'll have to plead ignorance on the Linq to Sql --- except to say that with the enterprise edition of SQL Server the server optimizer will see the reference to the aggregate on a column that it already has access to and pull from the index, regardless of your referencing the view.  I assume by your attempt to use the view, directly that you're not using the enterprise edition.

Comment: I'm actually rocking Express for development and Web for live deployment.

Comment: Just to say that if you are using an indexed view on an edition that is < enterprise then you have to add the WITH NoExpand hint to force it to use the indexed view

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you build a Stored Procedure that does both the vote insert and the update on the total votes. Then your application only has to know how to record a vote, but the logic on exactly what is going on when you call that is still contained in one place (the stored procedure, rather then an ad-hoc update query and a seperate trigger).

It also means that later on if you want to remove the update to total votes, all you have to change is the procedure by commenting out the update part.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this. I realize SP's have their place and this could definitely be one of them, but in my specific application I'm avoiding SP's at all costs.

Comment: Ah. In that case a trigger is certainly a viable option. :) An index on that field might make a SUM() fast enough to negate the performance issue without needing one, as well.

Answer (score 2):

The premature premature optimization is saving the total in a table instead of just summing the data as needed. Do you really need to denormalize the data for performance?

If you do not need to denormalize the data then you do not need to write a trigger.

Comment: The votes table will grow to tens or even hundreds of thousands records, and the total vote count will be displayed on nearly every page.  Yes I need to optimize it beyond summing it every single time.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: Don't knock it until you've tried it. I would suggest creating a table and generating fake data, then analyzing the performance of the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1):

My first gut instinct would be to write a UDF to perform the SUM operation and make `TotalVotes` a computed column based on that UDF.

Comment: +1 I suppose I'll have to research UDF and figure out how to do this :-s